# Using BIM360 Docs API How can we Retrieves a list of locations that we can allocate to an issue?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

Is it possible to get all locations list using BIM360Docs API? Our requirement is while creating an issue, user can select the location from the list of all available locations. And then save issue with the location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the API to get the list of Locations is still not exposed currently, engineering team is still working on this but pretty close, please pay attention to our BIM360 API update, or ping us after a while to check the status.

Comment: is this still the case or has the locations endpoint been exposed?